# Exclude JSON files from r.js optimizer

Tags: json, optimization, requirejs

I use a `config.json` file in my application to configure the application (big surprise) after deployment, pulling them in using the `requirejs-text` plugin. Ideally, I would like to keep this JSON file (among others) out of the optimized built file.

Here is my app hierarchy:

```
app/
   data/
       config.json
       ...
   scripts/
       main.js // require.config in here
       controllers/
           ctrl.js // Uses JSON files
```

My current build options (through gulp) for require.js are

```
{
    baseUrl: 'app/scripts',
    mainConfigFile: 'app/scripts/main.js',
    name: 'main',
    out: 'main.js'
}
```

Since these are just flat files I want to exclude and not modules, is there a way of keeping them out of the final file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you list it in the dependencies as `'text!config.json'`, you should be able to exclude it by listing it in `exclude` list as `'text!config.json'`.  I created a fake project to test it and it worked.

So:

```
{
    baseUrl: 'app/scripts',
    mainConfigFile: 'app/scripts/main.js',
    name: 'main',
    out: 'main.js',
    exclude: ['text!config.json']
}
```

Comment: Okay, so this answer definitely set me on the right path. There were a few more things that I had to change: I was actually using a `requirejs-json` plugin, so `json!` instead of `text!`, but I'm sure it just has to match whatever plugin you're using, otherwise it'll try to find a JS file. I also had to make sure this was defined in my `paths` hash in `require.config` (sorry, I didn't provide this info). Once I did those two things, it worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, er... you mention `requirejs-text` in the question, not `requirejs-json`. :) I'm glad I was able to help.

Comment: Yeah, sorry for the misdirection, the plugin choice is purely academic, but I did test it, and it excluded with `json!` but not with `text!`. I believe it has to match the plugin you use.

Comment: Yes, absolutely, they have to match.